# Menu items description? Custom Walker for wp_nav_menu()

Tags: theme-development, menus, walker

Normal Wordpress Menu looks like:

> Home | Blog | About us | Contact

But I've seen many pages with descriptions under these links:

> Home Page     |    Our Blogs     |    About us
>   |     Contact
>   ....meet us...| read more| basic info| contact form

How to achieve this?

(I want it to be core function for all my themes, so no plugins please, I just want to know how it's done)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You need a custom walker for the nav menu.

Basically, you add a parameter `'walker'` to the [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) options and call an instance of an enhanced class:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array (
        'menu'            => 'main-menu',
        'container'       => FALSE,
        'container_id'    => FALSE,
        'menu_class'      => '',
        'menu_id'         => FALSE,
        'depth'           => 1,
        'walker'          => new Description_Walker
    )
);
```

The class `Description_Walker` extends [`Walker_Nav_Menu`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/84f9592f88a19dd3fb4d1b8780679c99ea678688/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php) and changes the function `start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args )` to look for `$item->description`.

A basic example:

```
/**
 * Create HTML list of nav menu items.
 * Replacement for the native Walker, using the description.
 *
 * @see    https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/14037/
 * @author fuxia
 */
class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param  object $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param  int $depth     Depth of menu item. May be used for padding.
     * @param  array|object $args    Additional strings. Actually always an 
                                     instance of stdClass. But this is WordPress.
     * @return void
     */
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 )
    {
        $classes     = empty ( $item->classes ) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join(
            ' '
        ,   apply_filters(
                'nav_menu_css_class'
            ,   array_filter( $classes ), $item
            )
        );

        ! empty ( $class_names )
            and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $output .= "<li id='menu-item-$item->ID' $class_names>";

        $attributes  = '';

        ! empty( $item->attr_title )
            and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->target )
            and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->xfn )
            and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->url )
            and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';

        // insert description for top level elements only
        // you may change this
        $description = ( ! empty ( $item->description ) and 0 == $depth )
            ? '<small class="nav_desc">' . esc_attr( $item->description ) . '</small>' : '';

        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        $item_output = $args->before
            . "<a $attributes>"
            . $args->link_before
            . $title
            . '</a> '
            . $args->link_after
            . $description
            . $args->after;

        // Since $output is called by reference we don't need to return anything.
        $output .= apply_filters(
            'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
        ,   $item_output
        ,   $item
        ,   $depth
        ,   $args
        );
    }
}
```

Or, alternatively [as @nevvermind commented](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/6110/nevvermind), you could *inherit* all the functionalities of the parent's `start_el` function and just *append* the description to `$output`:

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) 
{
    parent::start_el( $output, $item, $depth, $args );
    $output .= sprintf( 
        '<i>%s</i>', 
        esc_html( $item->description ) 
    );
}
```

Sample output:

[image]

Now enable the description field in [`wp-admin/nav-menus.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/nav-menus.php) to get the ability to edit this field. If you don’t WP just trashes your complete post content into it.

[image]

Further reading:

- [Associated bugs](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=008094839757605916882:f6pwe-gmjka&ie=UTF-8&q=trac%20description%20nav%20menu&sa=Search&hl=de&siteurl=www.google.com/cse/home?cx=008094839757605916882:f6pwe-gmjka&hl=de)
- [Similar example with different markup and formatting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78065/73)
- [Enable description box in menu management screen programmatically](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78447/73)
- [Collect the item description for later usage](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78487/73)

And that’s it.

Comment: If for you **inheritance != rewrite the whole method, just keep the same name**, try this: `public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
    {
        parent::start_el($output, $item, $depth, $args);
        $output .= sprintf('<i>%s</i>', esc_html($item->description));
    }`

Comment: @nevvermind You should at least check if the description has some content. ;) The position of the description in my sample code is just the the most simple way to illustrate the solution. If you need to get the description into the anchor, you _have_ to re-build the whole function.

Comment: yes, you'd have to write the whole method, no doubt about it, but for people who need to (say...) append it, it might just save them a lot of head-aches. And this is all WP's fault. Arrrgh!

Comment: Nice one and I've used it in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159486/wordpress-change-header-list-items-to-div/12161295#12161295) by modifying a bit, may be you can make it better if I missed something, thanks.

Comment: What I actually needed **was** the *wp_nav_menu*, **but** I needed to change the 'container_class' parameter, to work for my particular use case, where I on some condition swapped the main menu for another one, but needed the classes to be consistent for css.

Answer (score 42):

Since [WordPress 3.0](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/3.0-branch), you *don't* need a custom walker anymore!

There is the [`walker_nav_menu_start_el`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/walker_nav_menu_start_el/) filter, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/walker_nav_menu_start_el/

Example:

```php
function add_description_to_menu($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {

   if (strlen($item->description) > 0 ) {
      // append description after link
      $item_output .= sprintf('<span class="description">%s</span>', esc_html($item->description));
    
      // or.. insert description as last item inside the link ($item_output ends with "</a>{$args->after}")
      // $item_output = substr($item_output, 0, -strlen("</a>{$args->after}")) . sprintf('<span class="description">%s</span >', esc_html($item->description)) . "</a>{$args->after}";
   }   
   return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'add_description_to_menu', 10, 4);
```

Comment: Nice! I was using the nav walker solution by @toscho, but this is much cleaner and easier to maintain.This should be the accepted answer, much better practice.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't better or worse than other suggestions; it's just different. It's short and sweet too.

Rather than using the description field as [@toscho](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/toscho) suggests, you could fill in the "Title" field on each menu item with the text you want, and then use this CSS:

`.menu-item a:after { content: attr(title); }`

It would also be easy to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to append it, but the text is ornamental enough that CSS seems appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can also write a `<span>` element after the navigation label in menus and use the following CSS rule to change its `display` setting (it's `inline` by default):

```
span {display:block}
```

Comment: Well its a simple and easy solution but why use `span` if you make it block anyway? xhtml/html4 not allows block elements inside links, html5 however does, so just use `div`, and no need for any css!