# remove menu items if user can't read

Tags: menus, navigation

I want to create one menu for all users and then hide / remove items from the menu if they don't have access to  the page the link leads to. This to me seem like an SOP. I really don't understand how this is not a core functionality. I can't possibly be the first one to want or think of such an idea. anyway

here is what i have so far I'm just not sure how or where to get the post id from

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'rm_menu_items', 10, 2 );

function rm_menu_items( $items, $args ) {
    foreach($items as $key=>$item){

        if (!current_user_can('read', $post_id)){
            unset($items[$key]);
        }
    }

   return $items;
}
```

Comment: interesting got down vote ....

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `'wp_nav_menu_objects'` filter, you get a list of menu items before the `Walker` processes them. Each menu item is a WP_Post object with some menu specific properties added in. The `ID` property is the post ID.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'rm_menu_items', 10, 2 );

function rm_menu_items( $menu_items, $args ) {

    $allowed_menu_items = array();

    foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {

        if ( current_user_can( 'read', $menu_item->ID ) )
            $allowed_menu_items[] = $menu_item;
    }

   return $allowed_menu_items;
}
```

You can see more details about menu items [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109569/limit-top-level-menu-items-on-wp-nav-menu/109573#109573)

Comment: right on .. what i like about this approach better than a plugin where I have to check who is allowed to see it this will just works off a flag that's already set :) i'll check it to make sure it works , but I'm guessing it will work out fine :)

Comment: seems to wipe out the entire menu.. I'll look into it more tomorrow :)

Comment: i see now if they are not registered then they can't read so this I am slightly off trying to use "read" permission as the toggle

Comment: Which posts are unregistered users not allowed to read? Do they share a common characteristic?

Comment: they all have content permissions enabled http://imgur.com/WNxYweS so that only users with a specific role can see them

Comment: That is not a WordPress option. What is the setting for allowing all users (including unregistered users) to see a post or page? If there isn't one, then you could change the conditional to allow posts and pages that do not have a content permission setting to be added to `$allowed_menu_items[]`.

Comment: yes you are right ,realized today that option comes from members plug in now on the hunt to find out how to read the access permissions from that plug in

Answer (score 1):

This was asked here a couple of years ago.

[Display navigation menu item conditionally based on user capabilities](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14171/display-navigation-menu-item-conditionally-based-on-user-capabilities)

There are several options there that would work.

Comment: This lead me to a plug in that works pretty well as a backup plan