# Allow html tags in WordPress Custom Menus Description Field

Tags: menus, filters

I added descriptions to my menus using this post, [Menu items description? Custom Walker for wp_nav_menu()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description). However I need to be able to use html tags and WordPress is stripping them out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the filter by adding this to your functions.php file:

```
remove_filter('nav_menu_description', 'strip_tags');
```

Answer (score 2):

In new wordpress we need add some mojo:

```
remove_filter('nav_menu_description', 'strip_tags');
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'cus_wp_setup_nav_menu_item' );
function cus_wp_setup_nav_menu_item($menu_item) {
                $menu_item->description = apply_filters('nav_menu_description',  $menu_item->post_content );
                return $menu_item;
}
```

Comment: This works, but when I add new page, it will put the entire content in it. Any way to circumvent this?