# How to create an automatic MultiColoumn MegaMenu with Categories WordPress

Tags: categories, menus, css

I'm looking for an easy to use step by step guide on how to create a MultiColoumn menu for categories on wordpress.

Actually in my blog I have 10/12 "main" categories and a couple of them have something like 50 Sub-categories and I will add more so I need something Automatic to show them in my menu.
Actually I have one but it is full of bugs. So I need something new please.

This is my CSS (you can also write it from scratch, maybe it's better :P)

```
.videoCssMenucontainer {margin: 2px 0 0;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu {background-color : #7F9DB9;width : 96%;margin:0 1.75% 10px 1.75%;font : bold 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;display : block;float : left;height : 33px;border-top-right-radius : 0;border-bottom-right-radius : 10px;border-bottom-left-radius : 10px;border-top-left-radius : 0;position:relative;z-index:10000;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu LI {display : block;margin : 2px 0 0 2px;float : left;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu A:hover UL, UL.ws_css_cb_menu A:hover A:hover UL, UL.ws_css_cb_menu A:hover A:hover A:hover UL {display : block;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu A {display : block;vertical-align : middle;border-width : 0;border-color : #6655ff;border-style : solid;padding : 2px;color : #444444;text-decoration : none;text-align : left;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu SPAN {overflow : hidden;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu LI A:hover, UL.ws_css_cb_menu LI A {padding : 9px;color : #763319;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menum LI A:hover, UL.ws_css_cb_menum LI A {padding : 4px;font-weight : normal;color : #000;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu UL {position : absolute;left : -1px;top : 98%;width : 160.65px;background-color : #ffffff;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu UL UL {position : absolute;left : 98%;top : -2px;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu, UL.ws_css_cb_menu UL {margin : 0;list-style : none;padding : 0 2px 2px 0;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu A:active, UL.ws_css_cb_menu A:focus {outline-style : none;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu UL LI {float : left;width : 150px;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu UL A {white-space : nowrap;text-align : left;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu LI:hover {position : relative;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu LI:hover > A {background-color : #fff;color : #000;border-color : #665500;border-style : solid;text-decoration : none;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu LI A:hover {position : relative;background-color : #fff;color : #000;text-decoration : none;border-color : #665500;border-style : solid;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menum LI A:hover {background-color : #ffc000;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu IMG {border : none;float : left;margin-right : 4px;width : 16px;height : 16px;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu UL IMG {width : 16px;height : 16px;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu UL, UL.ws_css_cb_menu A:hover UL UL {display : none;z-index : 99999;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu LI:hover > UL {display : block;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu SPAN {display : block;padding-right : 11px;background-position : right center;background-repeat : no-repeat;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu LI A TABLE, UL.ws_css_cb_menu LI A:hover TABLE {border-collapse : collapse;margin : -4px 0 0 -9px;border : 0 solid #000000;padding : 0;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu LI A TABLE TR TD, UL.ws_css_cb_menu LI A:hover TABLE TR TD {padding : 0;border : 0 solid #000000;}
UL.ws_css_cb_menu LI A TABLE UL, UL.ws_css_cb_menu LI A:hover TABLE UL {border-collapse : collapse;padding : 0;margin : -4px 0 0 -9px;}
UL.videoCssMenu {font-size : 13px;width : 96%;margin:0 1.75% 10px 1.75%;background : #7F9DB9;color:#FFF;text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.398438) 1px 1px 1px;border : 0 solid #000000;}
UL.videoCssMenu .videoMenuTitleImage {margin : -2px 0 0 -2px;width : 79px;height : 30px;}
UL.videoCssMenu UL {left : 0;background-color : #857DA2;width : 430px;}
UL.videoCssMenu LI A {color:#FFF;text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.398438) 1px 1px 1px;padding: 5px !important;text-transform:uppercase;}
UL.videoCssMenu UL LI A {overflow: hidden; float:left;}
UL.videoCssMenu UL LI {width : auto;float : left;height : 27px;}
UL.videoCssMenu LI:hover > A, UL.videoCssMenu LI A:hover {background-color : #ffffff;border-radius : 5px;border-color : #fff;padding : 5px !important ;color : #000;}
UL.videoCssMenu LI UL LI:hover > A, UL.videoCssMenu LI UL LI A:hover {background-color : #ecb899;border-color : #fff;padding : 5px;color : #000;}
ul.ws_css_cb_menu ul ul ul{background:#ccc;color:#142E51;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;}
ul.ws_css_cb_menu ul ul ul a{color:#142E51;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;}
.ws_css_cb_menum LI {width:auto;height:20px;}
```

And this is my HTML/PHP:

```
<ul class="ws_css_cb_menu videoCssMenu">
    <li><a href="http://downloadtaky.info" title="Downloadtaky.info | Download FREE Film IPA Serie TV">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Categorie</a>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul class='ws_css_cb_menum'>
            <?php wp_list_categories('sort_column=name&sort_order=name&style=list&children=true&hierarchical=true&title_li=0&dept=5&show_count=1&feed_image=/images/RSS.png'); ?>
        </ul>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Pagine</a>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul class='ws_css_cb_menum'>
            <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
        </ul>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Hack</a>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul class='ws_css_cb_menum'>
            <li><a href="http://proxy.downloadtaky.info">Proxy</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://hide.downloadtaky.info/">Url Hider</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://html2bbcode.downloadtaky.info">HTML 2 bbCode Converter</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Seo</a>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul class='ws_css_cb_menum'>
            <li><a href="http://pagerank.downloadtaky.info/">Pagerank</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://seo.downloadtaky.info/">FREE Seo Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://submit.downloadtaky.info/">Url Submitter</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Servizi CSS</a>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul class='ws_css_cb_menum'>
            <li><a href="http://buttongenerator.downloadtaky.info/">CSS Button Generator</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://favicon.downloadtaky.info/">Favicon Generator</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Generatori Link Premium FREE</a>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul class='ws_css_cb_menum'>
            <li><a title="Megavideo Unlocker, supera il limite di Megavideo" href="http://www.premiummu.com/megavideounlocker.php">Supera il limite di Megavideo</a></li>
            <li><a title="Fileserve, Megaupload,Uploading FREE Premium Link Generator" href="http://www.premiummu.com/premiumlinkgenerator.php">Premium link generator</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>
    <?php include('supsearch.php');?>
</ul>
```

I don't care about IE6 anymore, IE7 support will be enough, thank you to all for your help!

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of including the css and html and then just asking hey somebody code this for me?  What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Chris_O My question is have you got a working code or could you please take a look to my code and tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: @Chris_O Why you gave me a negative vote?

Comment: You didn’t say what you have tried already, what you want to get and how your problem relates to WordPress. It looks like a pure HTML/CSS issue.

Comment: @toscho @Chris_O the problem is related to wordpress because create a multicoloum drop down menu is quite easy if this menu is "static" and not related to wp_list_categories.
What I tryied is what you can see. If you want a live preview take a look to my website: http://downloadtaky.info, the menu on top is what I have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overloading the taxonomy **category**. Learn to use [custom taxonomies](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-taxonomy).  Some of your categories are in fact *series*, others belong into their own taxonomy too.

Replace the hard coded navigation `ul` with a [nav menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-menus) and look into the TwentyTen theme: it has a working solution for your problem. You can use your [own walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description/14039#14039) to adjust it even more.

But the first step to get a more professional look for your website is: drop Comic Sans. ;)

Comment: You are right Comic was a bad idea :-) I'll change it when I'll release my next template, as soon as I'll find a solution to my problem. Can I ask you to code it for me? How much will it costs? You are the only one who gave me a real answer instead of all bad reputation comments others gave me :-)