# add_filter to wp_nav_menu_objects having no impact

Tags: filters

I'm attempting to [add thumbnails to navigation items as per this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87017/pulling-featured-images-in-to-a-wordpress-menu). However, after adding the sample code to the top of my functions.php file nothing happens. I've whittled the code down in an attempt to get anything to happen. The code is now this:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'ad_filter_menu', 10, 2);

function ad_filter_menu($sorted_menu_objects, $args) {
    return '';
}
```

Still nothing is happening. The menu appears absolutely normally.

Heres the code thats generating the menu in header.php:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Relevant chat message: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23293130#23293130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

Your `ad_filter_menu` is a *filter* function: it filters/manipulates `$sorted_menu_objects`
That's why you always have to return the `$sorted_menu_objects`, and `return '';` won't work.

**Second:**

A better way to achieve the desired behavior (adding thumbnails to navigation) is to extend the [`Walker_Nav_Menu` class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3/src//wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L0)

There are several guides and templates out there that fix this for you, see for example [this previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16141/wordpress-custom-walker-for-thumbnails-with-custom-menu)

Comment: The `return ''` line was simply a way to test that the code is doing anything at all. That line should make the nav display nothing at all. Am I incorrect in thinking this?

Comment: Yes that is incorrect. Instead you can do `return $sorted_menu_objects = array();`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I should be using a custom walker! While the answer you pointed out seems quite outdated, it's gotten me well on my way to having a functioning thumbnail-enabled navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I can only suggest that you've got a 3rd party plugin or theme modification that is interfering somehow. I've tested your code exactly in several different installs and it works as expected.

A few other things to consider:

- Is your environment behind a cache of some sort?
- Are you working in a child theme?
- Do you have another plugin installed that is modifying or building the menus?