# Remove li from wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, navigation

How can I remove the li from wp_nav_menu? I know I can remove ul but is it also possible to remove the li? I would want to do this on just one menu not all the menus on my site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description/14039#14039).