# Any docs for wp_nav_menu's "items_wrap" argument?

Tags: menus, dropdown

I'm using **wp_nav_menu** and am trying to create custom output for the sub-level drop downs.  I came across the "items_wrap" argument but there's really not much information as to what it is, how it works, and what kind of things can be done with it.

What exactly *is* "**%1$s**" and "**%2$s**"?  (Can anyone explain it in layman's terms?)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The parameter `'items_wrap'` for `wp_nav_menu()` defaults to:

```
'<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'
```

This a a *template* that is parsed with [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/sprintf):

```
$nav_menu .= sprintf( 
    $args->items_wrap
,   esc_attr( $wrap_id )    // %1$s
,   esc_attr( $wrap_class ) // %2$s
,   $items                  // %3$s
);
```

The numbered placeholders – `%1$s`, `%2$s`, `%3$s` – refer to the arguments *after* the first argument in `sprintf()`. The percent sign marks a placeholder, the number the position and the type `s` means it should be treated as a string.
Do not change the type unless you really know what you do. :)

- `$wrap_id` is the parameter `'menu_id'` if you have it set, else it is `'menu-' . $menu->slug`.
- `$wrap_class` is the parameter `'menu_class'` if you have it set, else it is empty.
- `$items` is a string of the inner content of the menu.

Let’s say you don’t need a `class`. Just omit the second string:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s">%3$s</ul>' ) );
```

If you don’t need the `class` and the `id`, and you want another container (because you used a [custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description/14039#14039)):

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'items_wrap' => '<div>%3$s</div>' ) );
```

The main point is: You have to use the numbers for the replacements given in `wp_nav_menu()`. `%3$s` is always the list of items.

Comment: Thanks for trying to explain. I sort of see it but it isn't working out for me. I want to add say a class to my li items. You seem to be using ul for each item ? I don't see any sprintf in my code either so it's not clear.

Comment: @landed This is for the **whole menu**, not for each item. Please use our search, we have existing solutions for your problem.

Comment: I did search the web and others had the same issue I needed to extend the walker class and add my html there this worked ok for me but I had to copy quite a lot of code from the old class and rename it and change it then set the menu to use my custom walker class. Thanks

Comment: I may be a bit late to the party but if you wanted to introduce text to `items_wrap` how would you i18n it?

Comment: @henrywright Translate the values first, then pass them to the string.

Answer (score 0):

from what i gather it grabs an output and give the li a id and class with the menus name. So when you want to style a particular menu you grab its id and or class if you want to style it. the 1 and 2 is just a different output.