# Where do I add html code to the menu div?

Tags: functions, menus

When looking at header.php, I see the following line:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

That function is defined in nav-menu-template.php and generates the 'menu-custom-menu-container' div. Let's I want to add a div after the navigation list inside the 'menu-custom-menu-contaner' div. Where would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary'
                   ,'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s">%3$s</ul><div><p>content</p></div>' ) );
```

[See @toscho's detailed explanation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19247/4645) of the items_wrap parameter for more information.