# how to assign an ID to a wordpress menu

Tags: menus

The following code does not produce a UL with ID of "nav".  It just produces

```
<div class="menu"><ul>
```

This is the code:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1', 'container_id'    => 'nav';
```

According the [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) this should work.  Why isn't it working?

WP version = 3.5

**Update**

I now have:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="nav">%3$s</ul>', 'menu_id' => 'nav'));
```

but this doesn't work either.

Comment: make sure your theme doesn't filter `wp_nav_menu_args` and override your settings.

Comment: @Milo.  There is nothing in functions.php about this.

Answer (score 3):

According to that Codex page, you need to use `menu_id`. `container_id` only effects the surrounding div.

Comment: I think you're right, but it is still producing       <div class="menu">

Comment: yeah according to codex, but's it's didn't work

Comment: this is the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

The correct parameter for the `ul` is `menu_id`, and for the container `container_id`. But the `ul` works only if you pass …

```
'<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'
```

… as `items_wrap` argument.

You can hard-code the value like this:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array (
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="nav">%3$s</ul>'
    'theme_location' => 'top-menu'
    )
);
```

See [Any docs for wp_nav_menu's “items_wrap” argument?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/19245/73)

Comment: Thanks @toscho, but this did not work either.

Comment: I now have wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="nav">%3$s</ul>', 'menu_id' => 'nav'));

Comment: @Steve Disable all plugins. You break something very badly. My solution works in all cases.

Comment: I have disabled all plugins, and the issue remains: output is <div class="menu"><ul>

Answer (score 0):

As per my thinking `menu-1` must be the `ID` of your menu. Please read about the parameters [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Parameters) and provide appropriate parameters.

According to me your code should be like

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'menu-1', 'container_id'    => 'nav' ));
```

Comment: the menu parameter accepts an id from the database, not a CSS id.  It is a CSS id I wish to assign to the UL.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful, it was helpful for me to understand.

```
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu' => 0,
            'container' =>false,
            'menu_class' => 'nav',
            'echo' => true,
            'before' => '',
             'after' => '',
             'link_before' => '',
             'link_after' => '',
             'depth' => 0,
            'walker' => new description_walker())
             );?>
```

That would give your menu's random id when you create them. 
Hope it was helpful not sure if i understood the question right.