# Custom div to to menu wordpress afte <ul>

Tags: menus

Currently Menu is Like this=>

```
<div class="menu-footer-container">
    <ul id="menu-footer" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1526" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1526">About-us</a</li>
        <li id="menu-item-1527" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1527">Terms &#038; Conditions</li>
        <li id="menu-item-1555" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1555">Faq</li>
        <li id="menu-item-1528" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1528">Requirement</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want it like this

```
<div class="menu-footer-container">
    <ul id="menu-footer" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1526" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1526">About-us</a</li>
        <li id="menu-item-1527" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1527">Terms &#038; Conditions</li>
        <li id="menu-item-1555" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1555">Faq</li>
        <li id="menu-item-1528" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1528">Requirement</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="MYDIV">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **I want** is not a question. Please read [ask], then fix this post.

Comment: Also, you can easily do this with the [`items_wrap` argument](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19245/any-docs-for-wp-nav-menus-items-wrap-argument).

Answer (score 1):

As toscho mentioned this can be done with the [`items_wrap`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#parameters) argument. It would be something like this:

`'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s">%3$s</ul><div id="MYDIV"></div>'`

For more info [see here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#parameters).