# wp_nav_menu(), how to change <li> class?

Tags: theme-development, menus, navigation

I'm building a menu for my website. The static is looking like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="menu">
        <li class="item_1"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="item_2"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="item_3"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="item_4"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li class="item_5"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        <li class="item_6"><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        <li class="item_7"><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
        <li class="item_8"><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I've been able to understand how to customized the `<ul>` tag, to get rid of the automatic `<div>` tag. But now, I want to customized the `<li>` tag to be able to assign different `class` name to control specific behavior through CSS. When I use the `wp_nav_menu()` the output is as follow:

```
    <ul id="menu">
<li id="menu-item-111" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-111"><a href="http://mydomain.com/dummy/fashion/">Fashion</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-112"><a href="http://mydomain.comdummy/documentary/">Documentary</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-113" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-113"><a href="http://mydomain.com/dummy/events/">Events</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-114" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-114"><a href="http://mydomain.com/dummy/portraits/">Portraits</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I want to get rid of the `id` in the `<li>` tags and change the `class` to reflect the name of the page I want to link to. Basically I want to output the the same thing as the 1st snippet of code in this post.

The reason why I doing this, is that I use custom images that is controled by my CSS insted of plain text.

Is this possible? What strategy I should use to overcome this problem?

Comment: Here you can add different class in ul > li >a
https://sdtuts.com/wordpress-add-custom-class-in-wp_nav_menu-links/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a [custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description/14039#14039), remove anything you don’t need and add your classes. Here is a walker I use to get a list with clean markup: [T5_Nav_Menu_Walker_Simple](https://gist.github.com/1053467).

Your could also filter `'nav_menu_css_class'` or `'wp_nav_menu_items'`. But a walker class is easier to understand and to control in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks Toscho, I just find that in the new version of Wordpress (3.3) we can add custom class fir each menu items wich kind of solve my problem. I tried the script you suggested to me (T5_Nav_Menu_Walker_Simple) which does strip everything from the `<li>`, how can we control which elements we want to keep?

Comment: @Christian You can change the walker as you need, it is just a very basic example. To see which information is available, add a `print_r( $item, TRUE )` to each `li`. Then decide what to do with it. :)

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, what I needed was the **wp_nav_menu**, **but** I needed to change the 'container_class' parameter, to work for my particular use case, where I on some condition swapped the main menu for another one, but needed the classes to be consistent for css.

Answer (score 10):

go to appearance > menus - select the menu you want - go to "screen options" at the top right, select "css classes" - add a class to each menu item..

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `<li>` class to `nav-link`, as bootstrap 4.3 needs it:

```
function add_menu_link_class($atts, $item, $args)
{
    $atts['class'] = 'nav-link';
    return $atts;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_menu_link_class', 1, 3);
```

You can also unset the `id` attribute in that array.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple way to call `li` class and "any class" replace easily. Just follow the instructions.

Use this code in the nav area.

```
<?php
            $consult_menu = wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'theme_location' => 'topmenu',
                    'menu_id' => 'menu',
                    'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav m-auto',
                    'echo' => false
                )
            );
            $consult_menu = str_replace('menu-item', 'nav-item', $consult_menu);
            echo $consult_menu;
            ?>
```

Then inspect your code on the browser. find wp default class and than replace `str_replace(**"default_class_here"**,**"new_li_class_here"**,$consult_menu);`
| **Note:** ***$consult_menu*** here is my theme name, you can use any name here.

Answer (score 0):

As the last poster mentioned, you can add your own classes via *appearance > menus* with CSS classes ticked in the screen options. In the walker, you can access what you enter there via:

```
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' class="'. $item->classes[0].'">';
```

I have even used this to add pre-named images in the menu - a little flakey, but it works.

```
<img src="theme/images/navigation/'.$item->classes[0].'" width="48" height="48">
```