# Adding dynamic content to end_lvl in Walker Class

Tags: walker

I'm trying to add unique content to the end of each dropdown (sub-menu). I've managed to edit the end_lvl function of the walker class to add the div to the end of each sub-menu, but now I'm lost on the next step: creating a conditional statement based on the parent-menu-id to echo different content. Any thoughts/suggestions? This is what I have (and I know its obviously not working because I'm trying to use the item array but with menu-parent-id). Clearly I don't quite understand this.

```
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"sub-menu\">\n<ul>";
}

function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $item, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);

     if($item->menu-item-parent==37) {
        $afterMenuContent = "Content";
     }
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n<div class=\"after-menu\">" . $afterMenuContent . "</div>\n</div>";

}
```

Comment: Please show us your complete custom walker and how you determine the sub-menus that need extra content.

Comment: Can you explain what is going wrong with the code you posted? Nothing prints? Error message? Does `$item->menu-item-parent` give the correct IDs?

Comment: $item->menu-item-parent prints a zero all the time.

Comment: Also, toscho that is my complete custom walker, but I will update it.

Comment: You need to extend the Walker Class, not just include the functions. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39005/manipulating-menu-html for more.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
menu_item_parent
```

instead of

```
menu-item-parent
```

Can you show us the html output you want ?