# Tidy nav menu classes except for edit-menu-item-classes and active class

Tags: menus

I want to tidy the menu class and remove the `<li>` ID tags, but return the class which is added by CSS Classes (optional) and current class.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description/14039#14039), change the content in function `start_el()`.

I have written a [sample walker](https://gist.github.com/1053467) you can start with, you have to re-add the classes tough.