# How to make wordpress nav menu use post custom meta data

Tags: menus, post-meta, navigation

Using WordPress custom navigation menus automatically gets the menu item label and displays it between the of the menu item, what I need to do is to get a custom field value of the page and displays it instead of the menu item label. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description/14039#14039). Change the function function `start_el()` to use your custom field’s value.

Comment: Thanks very much, but I'm not a pro php developer :) . So can please hint me how to do that to display a custom field value INSTEAD of the menu item label, because when i remove the menu item label the whole item is automatically removed.