# How to create Loop code for Menu using Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, loop, menus

I have created a menu called "My Menu" in wordpress using Menus feature provided under Wordpress admin panel. I have added 3 pages into it named Page A, Page B, Page C.

I have applied featured image to all these 3 pages. Now what I want to do is, I want to create a code that will loop through this "My Menu" and print all 3 featured images of these 3 pages.

How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [add a custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu/14039#14039) to the `wp_get_nav_menu`. You can try a loop through `wp_get_nav_menu_items` as well