# Add tabindex to navmenu

Tags: menus

I would like to submit a "tabindex" attribute in a navmenu structure. The default options do not allow me to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a [custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14039/73) to change the output of `wp_nav_menu()`. The walker should extend the function `start_el()` to add your attributes where you need them. Another option would be a filter on `'walker_nav_menu_start_el'`.

But be aware that `tabindex` can make a page [less accessible](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/w3c-wai-ig/2005JulSep/0017.html). If don’t have an urgent problem to solve do not use `tabindex`.