# Select menu on browser resize

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes

I have seen on some wordpress themes that if the browser width is less, the normal menu becomes a select menu. Can someone tell me how it is done? 
I know there is a plugin for that, but I want to know how to implement it in the theme without plugin.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the plugin you mention is the one I wrote so if you're looking for answer on how to do it take a look at the code. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dropdown-menus/

Essentially all I did was create a [custom menu walker class](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu/14039#14039) so I could output the menus created in the backend as a dropdown.

If it helps my plugin can actually be packaged within in a theme and included via the functions.php. Just wrap the include in a `!function_exists('dropdown_menu')` test and you're good.

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved via [CSS Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), see [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) as an example. You'll find many resources if you search for "responsive" design.