# The concept of non-blog content

Tags: pages, content, frontpage

I'm fairly new to this wordpress stuff and wrapped my head around the blogging part.

Now it comes to the non-blog part of a webpage. I understood the principle of creating static pages and displaying them using various templates, but there is one major problem that i do not understand:

If i'm correct, i can have just one main-block of content for a page. For example, i could have an about section on my front-page and write it's content with the WP editor. But what if i need two or more sections? Should i create a (child)-page for every content-block and load it in the front-page's template file? This would be unnecessary bloating, wouldn't it?

Comment: Have you see [How to Create Editable Blocks of Text for the Homepage?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74519/how-to-create-editable-blocks-of-text-for-the-homepage/74524#74524)

Comment: Thank you, guess i'm trying what you call a custom-loop.