# Edit different parts of a page seperately

Tags: custom-field, page-template

I'm an experienced PHP developer without a lot of wordpress knowledge (yet!). I have to put together a fairly simple Wordpress page in the next few days.

To get started I need to create a custom home page that will pull in content from three other discrete parts and present them in one layout. I'd like to structure it so that on the administrative end you'd have three different pages or posts to edit and the content (an image, some copy, and a link) from each would get pulled into the front page and presented there.

What technique should I research for this? A custom page template? Custom fields? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [How to Create Editable Blocks of Text for the Homepage?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74519/how-to-create-editable-blocks-of-text-for-the-homepage)

Comment: Also look for different WordPress themes available. A front/home page with different layout is available with many wordpress themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few hours of research I implemented a solution using custom fields. To design my fields and apply them only to certain pages, I used the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. with this I created a set of custom fields for each page type that I needed to which I needed to attach specific content. Then I created a custom template for each of those pages in my theme directory, in which I access those custom fields with a simple call to the_field() function and process them for display. Wordpress made it very easy!