# Insert a div class inside wordpress menu

Tags: menus, sub-menu

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">About Assetline</a>
        <li><a href="#">Products & Services</a>
            <div id="mega">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Commercial Credit</a></li>
                </ul>    

                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio Management</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </div><!--mega-->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News & Events</a>
        </ul>
```

This is the menu structure what I want to integrate into wordpress . But there's an issue to add a div id (  ) inside of a menu . Any idea to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I think use [Custom Walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker).

First register a custom navigation menu for this list in your theme’s `functions.php`

```
class WP_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<div id='mega'><ul class='sub-menu'>\n";
    }
    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul></div>\n";
    }
}
```

After register custom navigation.
Usage below code in your theme:

```
wp_nav_menu(array ('theme_location' => 'your-theme-location', 'walker' => new WP_Walker));
```

Use a [custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78027/create-a-formatted-table-like-menu/78065#78065), extend the methods start_lvl() and end_lvl.

[custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78121/add-container-to-nav-menu-sub-menu)