# How to activate "Description" metabox for menu item programmatically?

Tags: functions, menus, metabox

I'm creating custom wordpress theme. How can I enable "Description" metabox for menu items (on nav-menu page) by default programmatically?

Comment: "WordPress already comes with the option to add a description to each menu item, but it is hidden by default." See: http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output

Comment: adrian7, how can I show this  metabox by default?

Comment: I will post an answer when I find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `description` from the user meta value `managenav-menuscolumnshidden`:

```
add_filter( 'manage_nav-menus_columns', 'enable_nav_menu_description_by_default' );

function enable_nav_menu_description_by_default( $columns )
{
    $desc_key = 'managenav-menuscolumnshidden';
    $hidden   = get_user_option( $desc_key );
    $user_id  = wp_get_current_user()->ID;

    if ( ! $hidden )
    {
        update_user_option(
            $user_id,
            $desc_key,
            array ( 0 => 'link-target', 1 => 'css-classes', 2 => 'xfn' )
        );
    }
    elseif ( FALSE !== ( $key = array_search( 'description', $hidden ) ) )
    {
        unset( $hidden[ $key ] );
        update_user_option( $user_id, $desc_key, $hidden );
    }

    return $columns;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to output the menu description here is a useful tutorial using WordPress Walker Menu class to enchance the menu [Wordpress Walker Menu Tutorial](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output)

Comment: Thank you nackle for your answer. But I need a little different thing. I need to enable metabox in admin panel, on nav-menus screen.

Comment: @nackle your answer is not related to the question.

Comment: It may not be related the the original question, but a search on here for "nav description" brought this post as the first result.  Which in turned answered the question that I came here with on how to display nav descriptions.  Upvote for that.