# Cannot control wp_nav_menu properly

Tags: menus

I'm having a little issue which looks like a bug but probably isn't. Here we go:

I simply have this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'nav')); ?>
```

Now, my issue is that I expect my output to be:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>My link</li>
</ul>
```

instead I'm getting:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
       <li>My Link</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can't assign my nav class to the ul. How do I do that?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19247/73)?

Comment: mmh, ok, I'm gonna have a look - but in the docs it says : $menu_class
(string) (optional) The class that is applied to the ul element which encloses the menu items. Multiple classes can be separated with spaces. Formerly known as $wrap_class.
Default: menu

Comment: There is also an argument `'container'` that should be set to an empty string ([example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78065/73)). You need it to change the … container. :)

Comment: which is this one i believe 'container' => false ... no?

Comment: Hm, indeed, that _should_ work.

Comment: do you have a menu created and assigned to this location?

Comment: Argh Milo you are right! stupid me, thought I set it up but i clearly didn't! Thx!

Comment: Yes, there is a bug. If you set a container false and use custom nav class, it will be setup on div. Remove `'container' => false,`to set custom class on UL element.

Answer (score 0):

As toscho pointed out the `container` argument should be left out or set to an empty string, and a menu should be created and assigned to the menu location (`primary` in this example).