# How can I Add a variable PHP in the Menu Nav

Tags: php, menus, variables

I want to add a variable in the Menu, for passing a value in all my page.
The purpose is to retrieve a value for transport to another web site (from my website links) to the tracking, this value depends on the origin of the user.

eg of my menu :

```
- Home = mylink/?partenaire=<?php
echo $myPartenaire;
?>

- About us = mylink/aboutus.php?partenaire=<?php
echo $myPartenaire;
?>

- Contact = mylink/contact.php?partenaire=<?php
echo $myPartenaire;
?>
```

I can retrieve the value in my page but not in the menu

1. I've installed this plugin to put PHP in my page 
   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/insert-php/
2. In function.php before "`?>`" at the bottom of the page, I've add :

   ```
   $myPartenaire =  $_GET['partenaire'];
   ```
3. In header.php
   At the beginning, I've add :

   ```
   <?php global $myPartenaire ;  ?>
   ```
4. In my page I can retrieve the value, I've add :

   ```
   [insert_php] global $myPartenaire ;  [/insert_php]

   <a href="http://mylink.com/mypage.php?partenaire=[insert_php]
   echo $myPartenaire;
   [/insert_php]">LINK OF MY PAGE</a>

   eg : mylink/contact?partenaire=<?php
   echo $myPartenaire;
   ?>
   ```

I know after how to get the value of "partenaire" in my page, but I don't know how to add the value

```
partenaire=<?php
echo $myPartenaire;
?>
```

in all the link in my nav menu.

Comment: Please take some time to learn how to format your posts, especially the code. I tried editing that and just couldn't make sense of it. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

You should never need a plugin to insert raw PHP code somewhere. There are always side effects you cannot see or fix easily.

Filter `wp_nav_menu_objects` instead, and add the parameter here to the URLs.

```
if ( ! empty ( $_GET['partenaire'] ) )
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpse_82194_add_param' );

/**
 * Add a parameter to item URLs.
 *
 * @wp-hook wp_nav_menu_objects
 * @param   array $items
 * @return  array
 */
function wpse_82194_add_param( $items )
{
    $out = array ();

    foreach ( $items as $item )
    {
        $item->url = add_query_arg( 'partenaire', $_GET['partenaire'], $item->url );
        $out[] = $item;
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot toscho, it works perfectly, but I've just noticed that when I click on the logo of my website, I lose the variable in the URL. I you click on http://disneylive-spectacle.fr/?partenaire=disneystore and after you click on the logo Disney Live, you lose the tracking, but if you click on "Accueil" = "Home", you keep the tracking. Is it possible to keep the tracking when I click on the logo, if not, can you tell me how to make the link on the logo desactivated? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the logo a nav menu item?

Comment: Yes, it's the logo nav menu.

Comment: No, the logo is not part of the nav menu. You will have to add the parameter separately there.

Comment: Thanks toscho, can you tell me how to modificate the parameters for the logo in the nav menu? I don't find the right file to do that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer on creating a custom menu Walker
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14039/6477

Then instead of adding a "description" as per the answer, you should be able to modify the href link.