# Is it possible to add a filter for the output of nav-menu items in admin?

Tags: menus, filters, admin-menu

I want to remove certain input fields on the admin screen for nav-menus for specific menu positions. I've used filters to filter front-end output but not for admin output. Is there a filter available for this purpose?

For example, I want to remove the option to add a `title` attribute to menu items, only if the menu is used in 'position-x'.

Filters such as `nav_menu_link_attributes` and `wp_nav_menu_args` all seem to be to filter the front end output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These fields are created in `Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit::start_el()`. To change or to remove them, create a custom walker ([example for another walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14039/73)) that extends `Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit` and uses other or less fields.

Then filter `wp_edit_nav_menu_walker` and return the class name of your walker.

Pseudo-code:

```
class Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit_Simple extends Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit {
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) 
    { /* Magic here. */}
}

add_filter( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', function() {
    return 'Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit_Simple';
});
```