# Customizing label/title output of admin nav_menu selecter

Tags: menus, admin, wp-admin, labels

On the left side of the menu editor, where you can add Page, Posts, Links, or Categories to a menu, how would I append a string to the title that shows up next to the checkbox? I've tried using `add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', ....)`, but that seems to only append a string to the menu item label on the front-end, and I just want it to appear in the admin post list. Our site uses posts as a calendar event, and the users want to be able to see the date as well as the title.

[image: for clarification of what needs to be customized]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141193/is-it-possible-to-add-a-filter-for-the-output-of-nav-menu-items-in-admin

Comment: That question addresses how to append a string to the menu manager on the right. What I need is a way to do that in the left hand side menu item selecter.