# Edit HTML of Wordpress navigation bar

Tags: navigation, html

Is there a way to change the html of my wordpress page's navigation bar? (I'd like to add in several divs that will be controlled with media queries.)

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Have you tried a [custom walker](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14039/73)?

Comment: @toscho No, I hadn't heard of that before reading the helpful responses below. That said, I've since decided to simply create my own header.php file in my custom child theme which lets me edit the html/css/php directly instead.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you'll need to implement the walker class for this.

Here is a simple example.

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container'      => 'ul',
    'menu_class'     => 'nav navbar-nav main-nav',
    'walker'         => new Primary_Walker_Nav_Menu()
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

In the above block of code, the `wp_nav_menu()` function takes `$defaults` as argument. In the array `$defaults`, the last key is **walker**. Te walker key's value is object of a class `Primary_Walker_Nav_Menu`.

#### In `functions.php` file implement the following code:

```
class Primary_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        if (array_search('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes)) {
            $output .= sprintf("\n<li class='dropdown %s'><a href='%s' class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" >%s</a>\n", ( array_search('current-menu-item', $item->classes) || array_search('current-page-parent', $item->classes) ) ? 'active' : '', $item->url, $item->title
            );
        } else {
            $output .= sprintf("\n<li %s><a href='%s'>%s</a>\n", ( array_search('current-menu-item', $item->classes) ) ? ' class="active"' : '', $item->url, $item->title
            );
        }
    }

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\">\n";
    }
}
```

The `start_el()` method is used to add the opening HTML tag for a single tree item (such as `<li>`, `<span>`, or `<a>`) to `$output`.

The `start_lvl()` method is run when the walker reaches the start of a new "branch" in the tree structure.

Generally, this method is used to add the opening tag of a container HTML element (such as `<ol>`, `<ul>`, or `<div>`) to `$output`.

---

#### The output of the above implementation will result in the following HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="nav navbar-nav main-nav">
   <li class="dropdown ">
      <a href="http://karunshakya.com.np/services/" class="dropdown-toggle">Services</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li><a href="http://karunshakya.com.np/services/selection-et-recrutement/">Sélection et recrutement</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://karunshakya.com.np/services/mise-disposition-de-personnel/">Mise disposition de personnel</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://karunshakya.com.np/services/gestion-de-salaire/">Gestion de salaire</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="http://karunshakya.com.np/news/">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://karunshakya.com.np/medias/">Medias</a></li>
   <li class="last-child"><a href="http://karunshakya.com.np/contactez-nous/">Contactez-nous</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

> How to use the Walker Class:
>   http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the relevant code and implementation in your answer.  If that link ever goes bad then the answer doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Edited. I hope my explanation helps in easily understanding the walker class.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only looking to change the *outer* elements (not the li's themselves) you can pass into `wp_nav_menu()` the `'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'` argument and edit it as needed, for example this shows how to wrap the list in a `nav` element and a `div` element:

`'items_wrap' => '<div><nav><ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul></nav></div>',`.

You could also pass in other elements to edit the content of the `<li>` and the `<a>` using `'before' => '', 'after' => '', 'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => ''`.

If that doesn't help please show the required **final** HTML output you're trying to get.