# how to add data to li for wp_nav_menu?

Tags: menus

I have `wp_nav_menu`

```
<nav class="site-nav links-to-floor">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#our-menu">Our Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Galleries</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I want to add  `data-id="1" data-slug="home"` to `<li>`

```
<nav class="site-nav links-to-floor">
<ul>
    <li data-id="1" data-slug="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li data-id="2" data-slug="our-menu"><a href="#our-menu">Our Menu</a></li>
    <li data-id="3" data-slug="events"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li data-id="4" data-slug="galleries"><a href="#">Galleries</a></li>
    <li data-id="5" data-slug="contact-us"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What is `data-id` ?? Is it menu id or just serial number for li elements?

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three options, depending on how extensive your demands are:

1. There is a filter towards the end of [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) that lets you change the function's output. If the menu is fixed you could use this to do a simple find and replace on the html-string. This is an easy solution, but if you change your menu, you have to change the function.
2. A bit more complicated is replacing the whole generation process of `wp_nav_menu` with a [custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu) that generates the data-elements from information you can pull out of existing information from the admin menu page. This is what you seem to have in mind.
3. The most complicated approach would be to add a metabox to the admin menu page, which would allow you to add different data-items for every menu item. You would then still need a walker function as well. Probably not worth the effort.

Comment: I suppose the answer will be resolved by option 2 and 3; modifying nav_walker and adding custom admin page.

Answer (score 0):

This is not proper approach but you can try jQuery like this to achieve desired output:

```
function add_li_atts_script()
{
?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery('#menu-item-276').attr("data-id","1");
    jQuery('#menu-item-276').attr("data-slug","home");    
    });
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head','add_li_atts_script');
```

For every new menu you need to add this 2 lines and need to give every `li` a new `ID` by default `wp_nav_menu` will generate unique `ID` for every `li`  :

```
jQuery('#li-id').attr("data-id","DESIRED ID");
jQuery('#li-id').attr("data-slug","DESIRED SLUG");
```